# .htaccess - How do I capture the incoming request`s HTTP Status Code?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

You know how Apache has many server variables like `%{REQUEST_URI}`, and `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}`

What is the variable name for the current request's HTTP status code?

I ask this because I want to write a `RewriteCond` that says 'if the HTTP status code is `302`, then...'. But I cannot figure out what the server variable for this would be.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: The code probably is NOT available, since it can't be determined until request processing is completed. e.g. there's no point in testing for a `200` code if you're doing "pretty" urls, because the pretty url almost NEVER exists as an actual file on the server. so by definition all pretty urls themselves are 404s. Only what they get rewritten TO would be a 200.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I appreciate the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *request* status code. Only the *response*, sent back from the server to the client, has an [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

The closest you can do is setting a [Custom Error Responses](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html) via an [`ErrorDocument`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive. This means, based on some status code e.g. `404`, you can call some server side script, which acts appropriately.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/html/errors/handle_404.php
```

This works for status codes starting with 400 and 500, but not for response codes in the range of 200 or 300. See again [Custom Error Responses](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/custom-error.html)

> Customized error responses can be defined for any HTTP status code designated as an error condition - that is, any 4xx or 5xx status.

---

Addressing comments, the syntax of `ErrorDocument` is defined as

> Syntax:    ErrorDocument error-code document

So there is just the `error-code` (4xx-5xx) to handle, and some document to show or execute, no way to define any additional flags.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I appreciate your concise answer. The error document will not help me, but now I know I need to find another solution to my problem.

Comment: Maybe [filters](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_filter.html) is another option, though I have no experience using those. You must look through the manual and see, if there's something appropriate.

Comment: Hey Olaf - thanks. Here is is what I want to achieve now: I have a php script and a apache rewriteRule that are creating an infinite loop... I want apache to only redirect to xwz.php IF xyz.php is not the one that just redirected to this current resource. I just don't know how to say that. Maybe you have some pointers on how this can be achieved?

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/html/errors/handle_404.php [R=200, L]` this the correct, if i want to pass `200 OK` response code for all `404` pages?

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSharma If this is a question, ask a new question! Apart from that, the "Syntax" part of [`ErrorDocument`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#errordocument) is pretty clear: Syntax: ErrorDocument error-code document. So no status code or flags anywhere.

Comment: @OlafDietsche already a question related to this topic exist : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70554192/overwrite-http-response-code-using-htaccess but no solution till yet and searching other part of stackoverflow