# HTTPS Redirection fixing multiple 301 redirect

Tags: html, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I want to redirect all request to `https://www.example.com`.

htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

my current code working fine but when someone enter `http://example.com` it taking two `301 redirect` means first it redirect to `https://example.com` and than to `https://www.example.com`

I want `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` with one `301 redirect`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to redirect all requests to `https://www` in a single request

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to crear your browser cached data before testing this new redirect.

Comment: Thanks for quick solution. Can you help me with this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70554192/overwrite-http-response-code-using-htaccess