# 200 OK with htaccess for 404 & 403 status

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpresponse

i am trying to change `HTTP STATUS` of `404` and `403` to `200 OK`

With PHP, it easy to do but the problem is my website is `.html` and i cannot change it to `.php` for some reason.

Code (PHP) :

```
header("Status: 200 OK");
```

i want same on `.htaccess`. so it will automatically change HTTP response code to `200 Ok` for `404` & `403`.

Htaccess Code :

```
RewriteEngine On

#ErrorDocument
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
ErrorDocument 500 /servererror.html

# Disable directory browsing 
Options -Indexes

#Change status code  to 200 OK
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <If "%{REQUEST_STATUS} in { '404','403', '500' }">
      Header set HTTP/1.1 "200 OK"
      Header set HTTP/2 "200 OK"
  </If>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How is 404 setup in your .htaccess as of now?

Comment: @nice_dev  `ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html` like this

Comment: So, if some URL isn't found, you return `notfound.html`. What could be the reason to send 200 status for a document that isn't found on server apart from 404?

Comment: @nice_dev yes right, if content or URL do not exists then it return `notfound.html` with `404` response code and all i want it to overwrite `404`  response code to `200 OK`

Comment: @nice_dev all i want, if any content/link to do not exist, it will return `notfound.html` with `200 OK` response instead of `404`. I want this because i am trying some dynamic content for error pages

Comment: By _dynamic content for error pages_ you mean custom error messages?

Comment: @nice_dev it not a custom message. It a different content like articles, deals etc. Can you help me how can i overwrite `404` to `200 OK`

Comment: I will test on some of my servers and get back to you. Apparently, `REQUEST_STATUS` isn't supported for the `If` block. So you can remove it.

Comment: @nice_dev got it. I will wait for your reply. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 3):

This was relatively simpler. Instead of local path to the document, you can mention full URL since the request gets *redirected* to this page to return a `200` ok status code . So, your `.htaccess` would look like

```
RewriteEngine On

#ErrorDocument
ErrorDocument 403 https://your_site.com/forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 404 https://your_site.com/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 500 /servererror.html

# Disable directory browsing 
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: With this code, if someone visit `example.com/anything-not-in-website` then it will show the content of `deals_page.html` page with `200 OK` response instead of `404` - Right?

Comment: How can i do this same with `403` response code to `200 OK`?

Comment: @shanmugapradeep Yes, it would for 404, you can test it with your site. For 403 it should not be done as it is a permission issue. I would rather suggest you to show appropriate error message not confuse the user using your system.

Comment: I am not confusing the user. example, i am trying to display message like `Oops, you landed on wrong but would you like to check our recent new year offer` and same for 403 like something `Access to this service is not allowed but you love to access our new year limited deal`. All i need the response code to show `200 OK` so the bot/crawler claw those pages.

Comment: BOT/crawlers always ignore the pages with `404` & `403` response code. this the reason i am trying to overwrite it with `200 OK`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep Ok, do you have separate .html files for `403`?

Comment: Yes, i do have. `notfound.html` for `404` and `forbidden.html` for `403`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep You can read this [`blog`](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/404-errors-google-crawling-indexing-ranking/261541/) if you are so concerned about SEO rankings.

Comment: I will check that article but it not just about SEO. There is many crawlers like listing, advertising etc, those crawlers ignore any pages with `404` or `403` response code. The reason i am just trying to change response code to `200 OK`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep Is it safe to say that you wish to return `200` ok response no matter what..?

Comment: Yes right, i want `200 OK` response code for `404` and `403`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep I updated my answer. Can you test it now?

Comment: @shanmugapradeep I made it more specific with `404` and `403` now in my answer. Can you test again at your end?

Comment: Not working. it still show `403 error` and it ignoring `error document 403`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep Share your .htaccess code in the question by editing it. Also, please don't tick any answer unless it works for you. I hope you know how it is done on SO here.

Comment: I have updated the code in question and i have added `HTTP/2` because in firefox it show it `version HTTP/2` and i made that tick for the previous code only for `404`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep I presume you could simply do `ErrorDocument 200 /forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 200 /notfound.html`.

Comment: Then it will redirect all `200 OK` page to `notfound.html` instead of 404 page

Comment: @shanmugapradeep I have updated my answer. Hope it helps this time.

Comment: It works! but it not what i am looking for. it redirect to the page. if someone enter `example.com/not-in-website` then it will redirect to `example.com/notfound.html` using `ErrorDocument 404 https://your_site.com/notfound.html` but i only want contents not a redirect. if someone visit `example.com/not-in-website` then it should show the content of `notfound.html` on same URL without redirecting and response code should be `200 OK` response code and that why i am using `ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep I am afraid that's the best I can go for looking at the limited options you have.

Comment: No problem mate. you tried best and i am thankful for your valuable time and helping me to find solution.

Comment: @shanmugapradeep "Access to this service is not allowed" - How is this "403" being triggered in the first place if this is seemingly a static `.html` site? (Although I asked this on your [earlier (dupe) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70554192/overwrite-http-response-code-using-htaccess) and you were unable to provide an answer.) The point is, if this is triggered by your application (after all, what else would be triggering this?) then you cannot override this with standard modules in Apache config/`.htaccess`.